# Google Map Not Loading Second Time In Modal AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have got the following directive:

```
    .directive('googleMap', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div></div>',
        replace: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watchCollection('elementChanged', function() {
                var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(50, 120);
                var mapOptions = { center: latLng , zoom: 12, myTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP };
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-container"), mapOptions);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: latLng , map: map, title: "example" });
                marker.setMap(map);
            });
        }
    };
```

So I can see the first time the elementChanged is selected the map loads correctly. However when it gets back the second time it doesn't load correctly anymore. I can verify that the elementChanged gets updated from the controller on click:

```
$scope.myClickFunction= function (element) {

    $scope.elementChanged = element;

    $modal.open({
        templateUrl: '/partials/myPartialForTheModal.html',
        controller: 'myControllerHandlingThatModal',
        resolve: {
            elementChanged: function() {
                return element;
            }
        }
    });
};
```

I have tried to log every time the directive gets called and it does, but I think the problem is in the map rendering itself.

Any help is much appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: is `elementChanged` defined in modal controller scope? Is map being created but just not visible? Create a demo that replicates problem. Might need to use $modal `opened` promise to make adjustments

Comment: I will create a Fiddle for it; it is showing the map frame but the map itself is gray. It appears the Google logo even, but is the content what isn't updated. A refresh on the page fixes the problem because it goes back to the first load of the map then. elementChanged gets passed through otherwise it would not render the first time either, would it?

Comment: Modal won't be available instantly and needs time to get some size probably especially when animated. I think might need to call maps `resize` shortly after modal opens

Comment: looked like by adding:

window.setTimeout(function(){
                    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');                
                    map.setCenter(myLatLng); 
                }, 100);

it fixes the problem as well as centering with the new lat lon.

Is that correct?

Comment: @CarlosTorrecillas - yes, it is a asynchronicity problem, but use `$timeout`, not `window.timeout`. ie `$timeout(function(){ google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize'); map.setCenter(myLatLng); })` no time indicator, you simply force angular to rerender in the next "digest".

Comment: Many thanks for that. It works nicely!

Answer (score 0):

i got same problem, just solve it by calling a resize after the modal shows up, in my case i use ngDialog, but if your component have any callback after open it does the work

```
            $scope.$on('ngDialog.opened', function(e, $dialog) {
                if (map) {
                    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {
                        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
                    });

                }
            });
```